# Recover deleted files from Perforce

Tags: perforce

I deleted a file from Perforce in the last month. Is there a way to retrieve it from P4?

If so, what command can I use?

Note: I'm not the admin for p4. And I don't want the file back in P4 but I just want it in my local workspace.

Also, I don't know the exact timeframe when I deleted it in last month...What command can I run?

I'm running P4 on windows. I'll appreciate if someone can provide equivalent command for windows

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use either the command line or the GUI, from the command line `p4 sync -f` forces the files to be resynchronized. For more information see the [Perforce Knowledge Base](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/1097).

Comment: I looked at this article earlier but it recovers & checkin the file back into P4. I just want the deleted file in my workspace & not in P4. How can I do that? Also, I don't know the exact timeframe when I deleted it in last month...What command can I run?

Comment: If you don't want it re-added, just sync to it and don't add it back, ie. just stop after the "p4 sync" command in the guide.

Comment: I tried p4 sync but its giving me error: Client 'my-machine' unknown - use 'client' command to create it.

Comment: Preferably you should do it on a developer machine or a machine that has Perforce workspaces set up already. p4 client isn't the easiest command to guide someone through, at least for me :) http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/client.html

Comment: 'p4 print' the previous revision, and re-direct the output.

Answer (score 14):

When you delete a file in Perforce, it creates a "deleted" revision, but the archive file is still there.

In the Perforce P4V GUI in the depot veiw, there is a filter symbol on top of the explore pane [image: Yellow Flag].

Click on this and select "Show Deleted Depot Files".

Find the file you want to restore and right-click on it. Select "Rollback..." and revert it to the previous revision of that file (before it was deleted.)

By default it will create a new changelist, be sure to select the one you want if you already have one.

On the command line:
`p4 sync //depot/folder/subfolder/filename@changelist`

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't committed the change list of deleted files to the repository, right click on the folder containing the deleted files in p4v and choose **Get Revision**. Be sure to check **Force Operation** and then Click **Get Revision**. Then the deleted files will be restored from p4 server.
[image]

ref: https://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/1479-how-to-restore-files-deleted-in-p4c-workspace/#entry4726