# How to I get the Perforce repo version of an file that was accidentally edited?

Tags: perforce

I accidentally edited the wrong file locally. The file is in a Perforce repo. What would be the best way to get the repo version, discarding the edited version and not changing other (edited) files?

For the question at [Is there an equivalent to git stash in perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104184/is-there-an-equivalent-to-git-stash-in-perforce) I see that `p4 shelve` could be a possibility?

Is another possibility to delete the file? And then follow [Recover deleted files from Perforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825687/recover-deleted-files-from-perforce) with a `p4 sync -f`?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is not open and you want to discard the edited version, either of the following will do the trick:

```
# Overwrite the local (unopened) file IFF it's different from the depot version
p4 clean FILE

# Overwrite the local (unopened) file no matter what.
p4 sync -f FILE
```

If the file is not open and you want to discard your local edits for now, but keep a copy of them (without submitting them):

```
# open the file for edit
p4 edit FILE

# shelve your local changes on the server for later recovery
p4 shelve FILE

# revert an opened local file to the depot version
p4 revert FILE
```

If the file is already open for edit and you just want to discard your local changes without shelving:

```
# revert an opened local file to the depot version
p4 revert FILE
```